# How to test whether two conditionals are equal?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, two-sample

I have samples from distinct joint distributions $p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)$ and I want to determine whether $p(y|x)=q(y|x)$. Is there an existing method for doing this?

Comment: Do you mean via some data?

Comment: Yes- I have samples from both joint distributions

Comment: For a specific x, you can do a goodness-of-fit test, such a Kolmogorov-Smirnov or Energy test. If you want to test for all x, you will run into the multiplicity/multiple-testing problem. You cannot test for ALL x, but some finite set could be do-able.

Comment: I do want to test for all x. I don’t think this should be impossible, since I can easily construct a two-sample test for equality of the joints (i.e. p(x,y)=q(x,y) for all x,y), which is a stronger condition than equality of the conditionals.